# If for all $a\in A$, $a\neq 0$ exists $b \in A$ such that $ab\neq 0$ then prove that $A\cong T_A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$A$ is a commutative ring with identity, and $T_A =\{ T_a \mid a\in A\}$, where $T_a=ax$ for all $x\in A$.

If for all $a\in A$, $a\neq 0$ exists $b \in A$ such that $ab\neq 0$ then prove that  $A\cong T_A$.

I've already prove that the function $f(a)=T_a$ is an epimorphism, and I don't get how does the hypothesis helps to prove that $f$ is one to one.

Is it really necesary?

Comment: Of course it's necessary. The only case where one-to-one$\iff$ onto for $f:A\to B$ is when $|A|=|B|<\infty $.

Comment: How do we put a ring structure on $T_A$? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Or an abelian group structure for that matter. Even if one tries to define it in the obvious way, how can well-definedness be shown without assuming the injectivity of $f$?

Comment: @user119394 You can check directly that it is a subring of $\operatorname{End}(A)$ (endomorphisms of $A$ as an abelian group).

Comment: @Roland Thanks, that clears it up. Instead of $T_a$ being an endomorphism, I mistook it to mean the _set_ of elements of the form $ax$ for all $x\in A$, that is $T_a = \{ax | x\in A\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(a)=0\implies \forall x\in A, ax=0\implies a=0.$$
Therefore, $\ker(f)=\{0\}$, and thus the claim follow.